# Use MemoryDataLayer to test in caffe

Tags: c++, deep-learning, caffe

Now I want to load a image from memory then pass it to network to test on it.

So I write code like this(judging https://medium.com/@shiyan/caffe-c-helloworld-example-with-memorydata-input-20c692a82a22#.nqoycpgsn ):

```
  bottom_in.push_back(this->bottom_vec);
  caffe::MemoryDataLayer<Dtype> *m_layer_ =  (caffe::MemoryDataLayer<Dtype> *)(this->caffe_net.layer_by_name("data").get());
  m_layer_->Reset(this->bottom, this->bottom, 1);
  this->caffe_net.Forward(bottom_in);
```

But it core dump.I check the data and ensure the data is passed OK.
So I check into the caffe and find that in Net class:

```
vector<Blob<Dtype>*> net_input_blobs_;
```

The size of net_input_blobs_ is 0, so

```
net_input_blobs_[i]->CopyFrom(*bottom[i]);
```

in Forward function in Net class goes wrong.

this is my proto about MemoryDataLayer:

```
layer {


name: "data"
  # type: "ImageSegData"
  type: "MemoryData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  # top: "data_dim"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    crop_size: 513
    mean_value: 104.008
    mean_value: 116.669
    mean_value: 122.675
  }
  memory_data_param {
    batch_size: 1
    channels: 3
    height: 480  
    width: 640 
  }
}
```

I am confused for this question for several days, Can you give me some advice or some example of MemoryDataLayer?